# Google tag manager: Is it possible to put CUSTOM HTML code in head tag via GTM?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I am currently using GTM to render all external scripts. I have successfully done that with Analytics and Adwords scripts. GTM renders them in footer.

However, google adword phone number tracking script requires to be placed in between head tags only. I am wondering if it possible via GTM. I am trying to do it by using 'Custom HTML tag' in GTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GTM still doesn't support AdWords call tracking skript from the box, it's easy to do yor own implementation, just add it as *Custom HTML Tag* and be sure to check *Support document.write*

See for example [this solution](http://www.search-star.co.uk/blog/2015/implementing-adwords-call-tracking-with-google-tag-manager)

Comment: This is working fine. I was worried about putting script in between head tags. However, it is not bothering me, GTM is handling it well.